# Finding pages through FTP

Tags: files, 7

Our YMCA organization just redesigned a new website as a static site. The old site was in Drupal. The domain and hosting have already been transferred. I have access to the old site through FTP and am trying to find specific pages in order to pick up content. Can anyone tell me where the web pages are in the FTP directory? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible @Donna, Drupal stores its pages and content inside a database. It's not easy to get those content pages (in the way they're supposed to look or be structured) without having a working copy of the old website.

Comment: From Drupal to static? That's a huge step backwards.

Comment: Yes @koivo is right. You may want to heavily reconsider moving from Drupal back to a static website. In fact, any CMS is probably more beneficial than having a static website these days.

Answer (score 3):

As @Beebee pointed out, Drupal stores its pages in a Database. That means the actual "pages" aren't going to be available via FTP.

The first thing you need to verify is, do you have a copy of the old Drupal website's database? If not, try reaching out to your old website host to see if they can recover it for you.

If the database isn't available, then your best bet to see the old website would be to use:

https://archive.org/web/

If you do have the old database, here's how you can set up and see the old website:

1. On your website host, set up a *subdomain* through cPanel (e.g.
   `drupal.example-ymca.com`)
2. Place a copy of all the old Drupal files inside this new subdomain directory (e.g. `~/www/drupal` - so the index.php file that comes with Drupal lives here: `~/www/drupal/index.php`)
3. Create a new MySQL database, user and password through cPanel (take note of each while doing so)
4. Import the Drupal database into this empty database
5. Open the `~/www/drupal/sites/default/settings.php` file and input your database credentials in the database config section
6. Visit your old website, e.g. `http://drupal.example-ymca.com/`

Here's a Google Search Result set that has additional topics:

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=drupal+transferring+from+host+to+host&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

I'd also like to point out, that it is possible to create/edit pages in Drupal by writing custom code (via an FTP if you wish) by using [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). This is a slightly more advanced topic, but nonetheless, a very important one to understand when working with Drupal. Once your site is up and running, locate any custom modules that implement hook_menu() to see custom pages (if any) that were created this way.